# Routing with angular and express when html5Mode is enabled

Tags: angularjs, http, express, url-routing

I have the route `'/iniciar-sesion'` in angular it retrieves the view with a controller, what i want to know is about express routing, could i create the same route in express to handle the get and post methods? if so how?

What i've done so far is:

- Angular routing (html5Mode is enabled)
- Created the express routes
- Declared the get and post functions

What happens right now is that when i don't have the express route angular render the static page, but when i have the express route it stays forever until it says `No Data Received`.

How do i tell express to send the data, and angular to receive it (with Restangular)?

**EXPRESS**

index.js

```
module.exports = (function () {

    var express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router(),
        signin = require('./signin.controller');

    router.route( '/iniciar-sesion' )
        .get( signin.get )
        .post( signin.post );

    return router;

})();
```

controller.js

```
module.exports = (function() {

    models  = require('../../components/db/models');

    function  get( req, res ) {

        models.users.findAll().then(function(users) {
            //Maybe i have to assign to res the users
            console.log(users);
        });
        console.log('Log In Get');

    }

    function  post( req, res ) {

        console.log('Log In Post');

    }

    return {
        get: get,
        post: post
    }

})();
```

**ANGULAR**

routes.js

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.users.auth')

        // Collect the ui-route states
        .constant('states', getRouteStates())

        // Configure the ui-route states and state resolvers
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'states', stateConfigurator]);

    function stateConfigurator($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, states) {

        states.forEach(function (state) {

            $stateProvider.state(state.name, state.config);

        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    }

    // Define the ui-route states
    function getRouteStates() {
        return [
            {
                name: 'signin',
                config: {
                    url: '/iniciar-sesion',
                    templateUrl: 'modules/users/auth/signin/signin.view.html',
                    title: 'Iniciar Sesion',
                    controller: 'SignInController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm'
                }
            }
        ];
    }

})();
```

controller.js

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.users.auth')
        .controller('SignInController',[function () {
            //Some restangular code
        }]);

})();
```

Comment: technically you *can* use the same name for a route on the server as on the client, since you aren't using html5Mode, the client route will be prepended with `#` so it won't be an exact match anyway.  However, you really *shouldn't* use the same name for two different routes; not only is it confusing, but it can cause issues if you were to refresh the page rather than navigate from another page, especially if you enable html5Mode.

Comment: i have `html5Mode` enabled, what you mean by _same name for two diff routes_ ?

Comment: your code didn't show html5Mode in your routes.js, so I assumed you weren't using it.  However, the point remains that you have two different routing engines, (express and angular).  Express handles a route when a page is requested from the server (page reload, etc), angular handles routes by using PushState.  if you define the same route in both, when you navigate to the page in angular it will push the url into the browser, where if you hit refresh (page reload), you would get the server data instead of the page you just navigated to.

Comment: so basically i cant have same route names in express and angular at the same time?

Comment: correct, you cannot have identical routes in both frameworks.

Comment: Thanks @Claies, i guess there wont be right answer for this, then what could be a nice convention for naming the routes? in this case the project will be in spanish, so angular routes must be in spanish, and i guess i'll use english to name express routes...

Comment: in my opinion, unless you want the user to directly access the data without the assistance of the UI, the name of the server endpoint shouldn't really matter, but should be something that is meaningful to the developer team while meaning nothing to the end user.

Comment: thanks @Claies, now that you mention that, how could i avoid to display the content of the `response.json(data);` in the browser when the a client access to the route?